# Docker doesn't download images (connection problems to registry)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

I installed docker with the official tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

**My connection problem:**

When I execute `docker run hello-world`, I get the following output:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
```

Then docker waits 7-8 minutes, and outputs:

```
Error parsing HTTP response: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "408 Request Time-out Your browser didn't send a complete request in time"
```

It does also not work to login to dockerhub with `docker login`. When I enter wrong userdata, I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

But when I enter correct data, I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

When I curl the URL from the message (`curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`) I get

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

**Docker and Ubuntu version:**

```
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990

Linux jo-desktop 4.2.0-34-generic #39~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:38:02 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**What I already checked:**

a) `sudo ufw status` outputs `Status: inactive`

b) It's a home network, where all devices are connected to a DSL-Router. Docker works on other devices which are connected to this router

c) Docker has the same connection problems on a virtual machine, whose host is the ubuntu I'm working on. So it seems to be a network problem of the Ubuntu I'm using

d) There were other people having my problem (e.g. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20628). So I changed the MTU for my eth0 and for docker to 1500. It does not change anything.

**Ideas on how to find the problem?**

Does somebody have Ideas what more I could try to find out, which component blocks the correct connection to the docker registry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem:

I had to set the MTU for my network interface to 900.

Comment: Another info: This works, but then I had network problems from inside the docker container. Solution was: Use another network interface. My Ubuntu 14.04 seems to have problems with the network interface on my mainboard, so I bought a usb network interface, now everything works without MTU Change or something else.